# Show cursor in screen shot

Tags: macos, shortcut, screen-capture

Is it possible to take a screen shot, using hotkeys, where the cursor will not disappear? I am making a short tutorial and it would save me time to have the cursor present, as opposed to post-processing the images.

For example, if there is a button I could press in addition to <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> to copy a screen portion to the clipboard, including the cursor, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Grab Application.  It allows you to superimpose the cursor on screen captures.  Just go into Grab preferences and select the cursor.  When you click on the screen to take the screenshot, Grab will "place" the cursor where you click. This works for Window capture. Choosing a pointer from the preference window enables this to work when capturing a window shot.

Comment: It appears that this only works when capturing an entire window, or the entire screen, and not for a selection. It also doesn't work with any shortcuts outside the Grab application. Is there no way to do it system wide without opening Grab? Or to do it with only a selection?

Comment: @spacetyper you can crop the image after the fact...

Answer (score 2):

If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd>, a different screen capture screen appears and there is a button at the bottom called Options. Press that, and a menu pops up with an option to 'Show Mouse Pointer'. Select that and the mouse cursor should be included in the screen capture.

Comment: Nothing happens for me with this shortcut. What OS are you on?

Comment: Catalina right now. When I wrote the answer, probably Mojave. I just tested it - it still works

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm on High Sierra so I guess it was added after

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Grab. After starting Grab, go to preferences and chose a pointer. Now when you capture a window, the cursor will be shown. Choosing a pointer from the preferences window enables that pointer to be visible in a window capture.